# Is there an onResume method in Angular similar to Android View Lifecycle?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, lifecycle

In my application, a user can switch between multiple tabs. Each tab is linked to a different component.

Example: User is on URL1, on button click he navigates to URL2 in a new tab. When I manually switch back to URL1, is there any method which is triggered just like `onResume` function in `Android`?

Comment: Are these browser tabs or HTML sections within a document?

Comment: @marekful these are browser tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@HostListener` on `window`'s `focus` event on your component like below.

```
export class AnyComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostListener('window:focus', ['$event'])
  tabActivation(event) {
    console.log("TAb activated")
  }

}
```

You can also use `blur` event to detect "deactivation" of tab.

```
@HostListener('window:blur', ['$event'])
tabDeactivation(event) {
        console.log("TAb deactivated")
}
```

Comment: `focus` is being called multiple times, is there any other method which loads only once or should I use my own local variable to handle it?

Comment: Can you please make one `StackBlitz` demo? @Anirudh